# Imagery Hybrid in ReactLeaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I have been using the library react-leaflet@npm:3.1.0 with the `Esri WorldImagery` layer provided in [leaflet extras in Github](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/). Over there I can get the url for tileLayer:

```
var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2v7t59h/31/) is a sample of the `World Imagery Map`.

I have been searching for an alternative to get street names while keeping the World Imagery layer. For instance, [ArcGIS Developers page](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/maps/services/basemap-layer-service/#basemap-styles-service-url) is offering this type of layer.

Do you know any similar configuration which can be applied to `World Imagery` using react-leaflet?